# css pseudo elements and position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position, pseudo-element

I added a img as a pseudo element to be able to change its opacity without effecting the parent containers opacity

the pseudo element position is set to absolute and relative to parent to place it inside the parent div `section-1`

why are all children of `section-1` required to setting there position to
`relative` to be visible ?

```
.section-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* background-color: rgb(228, 223, 176); */
}

.section-1::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTjz.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: bottom;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /* Add change */
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

[![test][1]][1]

[1]:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;

  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.section-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* background-color: rgb(228, 223, 176); */
}

.section-1::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTjz.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: bottom;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /* Add change */
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-content {
  /* Add margin specific */
  position: relative;
}

.section-2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/* https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTjz.jpg */
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="section-1">
      <div class="navigation-bar">
     

        <nav class="header-nav">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="header-content">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque,
          animi? Expedita, id et. Distinctio libero vitae itaque, sit quaerat,
          cupiditate tempora repudiandae minus quam provident ea, cumque
          perferendis saepe laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="#">44</a>
      </div>

      <div class="curios">
        <p>wewewewewew</p>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
```

Comment: Why? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: how does `position: relative` effect the z-index ?

Comment: Whether an element is positioned or non-position helps determines stacking context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Stacking without the z-index property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index)

When the `z-index` property is not specified on any element, elements are stacked in the following order (from bottom to top):

1. The background and borders of the root element
2. Descendant non-positioned blocks, in order of appearance in the HTML
3. Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance in the HTML

---

In your example, `.section-1` is relatively positioned so creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). `.section-1::before` is absolutely positioned, so will stack higher than any non-positioned elements in the same stacking context.

[image]

---

As soon as `.navigation-bar` and `.header-content` are relatively positioned, they will stack higher than `.section-1::before` (because they appear after `.section-1::before` in the HTML).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use `z-index`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.section-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* background-color: rgb(228, 223, 176); */
  z-index:0;
}

.section-1::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTjz.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  background-position: bottom;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  /* Add change */
  opacity: 0.75;
  z-index:-1;
}

.navigation-bar {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-content {
  /* Add margin specific */
}

.section-2 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/* https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPTjz.jpg */
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="section-1">
      <div class="navigation-bar">
     

        <nav class="header-nav">
          <a href="#">1</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
          <a href="#">2</a>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="header-content">
        <h1>header</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque,
          animi? Expedita, id et. Distinctio libero vitae itaque, sit quaerat,
          cupiditate tempora repudiandae minus quam provident ea, cumque
          perferendis saepe laborum.
        </p>
        <a href="#">44</a>
      </div>

      <div class="curios">
        <p>wewewewewew</p>
      </div>
    </div>

   
  </body>
```